# Making a continuous slideshow - use jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, image, slideshow

I need to make a continuous slideshow that is started when the page is loaded.

When the user hovers over it, the slideshow pauses and a caption slides up. When the user puts his cursor elsewhere the caption slides down and the slideshow continues. When the user clicks on an image in the slideshow, he/she will be directed to the appropriate HTML. I can use any type of code. I'm not an experienced programmer so you'll have to really detail it. I don't have any jQuery knowledge but I can use it this time maybe. This may have been asked before but I couldn't find it.  Sorry for my poor English.

EDIT: Something like http://www.cartoonnetwork.co.uk/ (starts automatically, stops on mousedown etc.) on the top though I wish it would continue when the mouse moves off. I've never programmed with flash before so maybe it can be anything other than flash?

I can use these languages:

- HTML(5)
- CSS
- JavaScript
- jQuery

I'll try to do it with other languages like flash but it would be nicer with those mentioned because I have used them(excluding jQuery).

EDIT 2: I like [Orbit](http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery_image_slider_plugin)(thanks, Michael!) and all the sliders that have a timer

NB: I have no money to spend on anything so keep that in mind.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this, including detailed tutorials:

http://naldzgraphics.net/tutorials/25-must-learn-slider-tutorials-with-jquery/

http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2011/10/jquery-image-slider-plugins.html

http://www.designyourway.net/blog/resources/28-useful-jquery-sliders-you-need-to-download/

http://webdesignfan.com/jquery-slider-tutorials-and-plugins/

http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-image-galleries/

http://machoarts.com/21-beautiful-jquery-sliders-for-your-next-project

http://designmodo.com/jquery-image-sliders/

Comment: Thanks! I didn't find quite what I wanted but I found Orbit which looks great on my HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

you'll find a lot of jquery plugins which do what you want.
[Here](http://www.themeflash.com/30-powerful-jquery-slideshow-sliders-plugins-and-tutorials/)

Answer (score 0):

You may make an HTML like this:

```
<div class="main_view">
                        <div class="window">
                            <div class="image_reel">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img width="948" src="Images/Home/LIV.jpg" alt=""></a> <a href="#">
                                        <img width="948" src="Images/Home/JUM.jpg" alt=""></a> <a href="#">
                                            <img width="948" src="Images/Home/LOV.jpg" alt=""></a> <a href="#">
                                                <img width="948" src="Images/Home/BLI.jpg" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pictureslide">
                                <h2>
                                    Livestrong</h2>
                                <p>
                                    Mobile donations to fight cancer and improve lives.</p>
                                <a href="http://thirteen23.com/work/#livestrong-donation">See more</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pictureslide">
                                <h2>
                                    Jumpshot</h2>
                                <p>
                                    The lighter side of serious software.</p>
                                <a href="/#jumpshot">See more</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pictureslide">
                                <h2>
                                    Flashback</h2>
                                <p>
                                    An exciting way to explore, stylize, and share your Facebook photos.</p>
                                <a href="/#flashback">See more</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pictureslide">
                                <h2>
                                    Love Universe</h2>
                                <p>
                                    Blurring the line between product and lifestyle.</p>
                                <a href="/#love-universe">See more</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="paging">
                            <a href="#" rel="1">
                                <img src="Images/Home/LIV_sm.jpg" alt=""></a> <a href="#" rel="2">
                                    <img src="Images/Home/JUM_sm.jpg" alt=""></a> <a href="#" rel="3">
                                        <img src="Images/Home/LOV_sm.jpg" alt=""></a> <a href="#" rel="4">
                                            <img src="Images/Home/BLI_sm.jpg" alt=""></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

then your JS:

```
var MainPageSlider = function (windowObj,element) {
    var parent = $("#"+element);//element is the ID of the Master/Parent of this HTMLCode
    parent.data('imagewidth', windowObj.imageWidth);
    parent.data('imageSum', windowObj.imagesum + 1);
    $(".paging a:first", parent).addClass("active");
    var intervalCulture;
    var imageReelWidth = parent.data('imagewidth') * parent.data('imageSum');

    $(".image_reel", parent).css({ 'width': imageReelWidth });

    rotate = function () {
        var triggerID = $active.attr("rel") - 1;
        var image_reelPosition = triggerID * (parent.data('imagewidth') + 30);
        $(".paging a", parent).removeClass('active');
        $active.addClass('active');

        $(".image_reel", parent).animate({
            left: -image_reelPosition
        }, 500);
    };

    rotateSwitch = function () {
        play = setInterval(function () {
            $active = $('.paging a.active', parent).next();
            if ($active.length === 0) {
                $active = $('.paging a:first', parent);
            }
            rotate();
        }, 7000);
    };
    rotateSwitch();
    $(".image_reel a", parent).hover(function () {
        clearInterval(play);
    }, function () {
        rotateSwitch();
    });

    $(".paging a", parent).click(function () {
        $active = $(this);
        clearInterval(play);
        rotate();
        rotateSwitch();
        return false;
    });
};
MainPageSlider(windowObj,'element');//element is the Parent of this HTML
```

And then add proper styles to your code.
Also, write a function for hover as you require.

Comment: Please make Sure you adjust Width & Heights of your images properly. you may use Custom Widths. For Main_view do not forget to add `style='overflow:hidden;'`